# Play but don't record avaudioplayer background music

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avaudioplayer, avassetwriter

I have an app that records a video/audio like Instagram stories with `avassetwriter` and simultaneously plays an audio background music file with `avaudioplayer`. It both records and plays great.

The problem I am noticing though, is when I play back the recording, the background music is extremely loud, and I'm assuming it's because the mic and the bottom-of-the-phone default speaker, through which the audio background music is playing out of, are situated right next to each other - even though when I record it sounds like it's not that loud.

Is there any possible way or workaround that results in allowing the background music to play while recording but to not have it actually be recorded? I'm stumped on what my options are, and am desperately hoping to see if anyone else had any ideas/thoughts as I couldn't find any existing content addressing this issue.

Comment: what api are you using for recording? there are "voice processing" configurations that do echo cancellation, with several caveats

Comment: @RhythmicFistman im using avfoundation

Comment: Which `AVFoundation` API? There's at least `AVAudioEngine`, `AVCaptureSession` and I guess `AVAudioRecorder`.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman oh sorry i'm using avcapturesession

Comment: Pretty sure `AVCaptureSession` has no explicit voice/echo cancellation support. You could try setting `captureSession. automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false` and then configuring `AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat` on your `AVAudioSession`.